# the preview don't show after I updated android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

after i updated android studio from version 3.0.1 to 3.1.2 i can not see the preview. I waited a lot but the preview does not load.

What to do? and thank you.

Comment: Preview for what? XML layouts?

Comment: for xml layout and design

Comment: There's a little button on the right that says "preview". Did you click that?

Comment: yes in design and in xml code i cannot see the preview

Comment: change the api.. may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 3 hours: problem solved !!! I changed the version of SDK in build.gradle (module: app)